# Saving to directory path by including variable in the export pdf name

Tags: variables, pdf, export, weasyprint

I am trying to export a pdf using Weasyprint and Jinja2 on Python. Saving and exporting the pdf work fine but the problem is that I want to pass a variable into the path. Hereby, my variable is 'title' and I want all my pdf to take the 'title' variable and to export it.

```py
title = df.iloc[1,0] #created my title variable

template_vars = {"title": title, "start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date, "price": price, 
                 "total_Impressions": total_impressions, "art_work": art_work, "total_Clicks": total_clicks,
                 "cpm":cpm, "image_path": image_path} #created my dictionary 

html_out = template.render(template_vars)
print(html_out) #rendered my template

HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf("D:/Course/learning-automation/{title}.pdf",
    stylesheets=[CSS('D:/Course/learning-automation/style.css')]) # tried to enter the title variable in the exported pdf path.
```

The actual result is that the pdf is exported but the variable does not appear in the name. Thanks for your help.